# HandleErrorAttribute Add Exception Message to ModelState and continue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, handleerror

I would like to catch all the DbEntityValidationException messages, add them to the ModelState and continue to the view that caused the Exception which would display the ModelState errors using @Html.ValidationSummary()

I've got everything working except the Extension class for HandleErrorAttribute I've written only redirects to the /Shared/Error view 
OR if I write - 
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
it returns a blank view

```
 public class HandleLogErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    //Log the filterContext Exception Details
    public override void OnException ( ExceptionContext filterContext )
    {
        var exception = filterContext.Exception;
        var controller = ( (Controller) filterContext.Controller );

        //Log here 

        //Add Validation Exception messages to ModelState here
        if ( exception is DbEntityValidationException ) {
            var dbEx = filterContext.Exception as DbEntityValidationException;
            foreach ( var ves in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors ){
                foreach ( var ve in ves.ValidationErrors ) {
                    controller.ModelState.AddModelError( string.Empty, ve.ErrorMessage );
                }
             }
             //HOW to continue to the View that caused the exception with the model state now filed with the Validation Exceptions?

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of the `HandleErrorAttribute` to display an error page when an exception occurs (not to return the view) and you don't have access to the model so you could not return the view anyway. If you want to return the view with an error message, catch the exception in the POST method, add a `ModelStateError` and return the view.

Comment: I've got that working using the Validation with a Service layer structure concept from http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-%28data%29/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs   But this ties the service layer to a ModelStateDictionary. Which means DI wont work. So I'm thinking of ways to return business rule errors and then push them thru to the model state from the Service Layer